# Linux Mint 13 Xfce window button disappeared & no mouse cursor in text mode

Tags: xorg, linux-mint, xfce, window, cursor

I am using Linux Mint 13 Xfce version on VBox. After one month without any problem suddenly today I noticed that the min-max-close buttons on all windows have disappeared.

Secondly, I can write in gedit, but I cannot see the blinking mouse cursor while coding. It is somehow wierd.

I tried:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

but still it is the same problem.....

Answer (score 1):

Settings -> Session Startup

add xfwm4 entry:

```
name: xfwm4
command: xfwm4
```

Explenation, the windows manager for some reason is not loaded. You just force linux to load xfwm4 at the start up.

Answer (score 0):

Check settings for the window manager and keyboard - either by invoking the settings manager from the XFCE menu or by running `xfce4-settings-manager`.